# What does "Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold" mean when I enter "dpkg -l" in the command prompt?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, dpkg

It appears to be an error. I'm not sure if I should worry about it or not.

FYI: I'm just picking up Ubuntu (10.04) and want to develop a core understanding of how it all works, which is why I'd like to know what this all means. I don't have specific problem that needs solving.

Comment: This is an old question, but still valid, though not so much a programming question. Would probably be better if moved to https://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It shows you the current state of the package as the package-manager sees it.  It's specifically talking about the 1st letter of the first column.

```
root@pbx1:/var/lib/openfire/plugins# dpkg -l |more 
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold | Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                                Version                      Description
+++-===================================-============================-==========================================================================
ii  acpi                                1.5-2                        displays information on ACPI devices
ii  acpi-support-base                   0.137-5                      scripts for handling base ACPI events such as the power button
ii  acpid                               1:2.0.7-1                    Advanced Configuration and Power Interface event daemon
```

For example... the "acpi" package, the 1st column says "ii " which means... we requested it to be installed, it is installed, and currently there are no errors.  (desired = `I`nstalled, Status = `I`nst, and Err = `(none)`)

The key is to look at the capital letter for each value.  i.e. desired can be "u, i, r, p, h" and status can be "n, i, c, u, f, h, w, t" and finally, the Err column can be "[nothing], r"

Comment: I've just realised those pipes on the lhs are supposed to be an ascii line to the first column (as for the second and third)!

Answer (score 0):

That is a column header for the (single letter) column indicated with the line coming down from it.